# How to measure changes to the filesystem done by a certain application?

Tags: filesystems, osx, tracing, dtrace

I am using a command line application which creates a great amount of intermediate artifacts to the file system and then at some point deletes them.

On environments where storage space is constrained this can pose a problem.

I'd like to know if there's a tool which would allow me to run the application under and then summarise the changes that were done to the filesystem when it terminates (mainly amount of created/deleted files and their sizes).

Answer (score 3):

Any useful tool in this area is going to require some learning effort.  The usual approach is *auditing*, which OSX provides:

- [Audit in a OS X System](https://www.scip.ch/en/?labs.20150108)
- [How to Audit/log file access events on MAC OS X?](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/562291-how-to-audit-log-file-access-events-on-mac-os-x)
- [How can I track which program is deleting my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161580/how-can-i-track-which-program-is-deleting-my-files)

Other tools can be useful:

- [How to monitor file access for an OS X application?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/how-to-monitor-file-access-for-an-os-x-application)
- [See what process is using a file in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317177/see-what-process-is-using-a-file-in-mac-os-x)

But ultimately, the responses to this question will be based on the responder's familiarity with certain tools.